# Binary search tree function definition error

Tags: data-structures

This is the part of code where I want the createNode function to return the node that it creates.

```
struct Node *ptr = createNode(key);
if(key<prev->data)
{
    prev->left = ptr;
}
else
{
    prev->right = ptr;
}
```

createNode Function :-

```
Node * tree :: createNode(int key). //Unknown type name 'Node'
{
    Node * n = new Node;
    n->data = key;
    n->left = NULL;
    n->right = NULL;
    return n;
}
```

declaration of function in class:-

```
Node * createNode(int key);
```

structure of Node :-

```
struct Node
    {
        int data;
        Node *left;
        Node *right;
    };
```

when I define the function createNode i'am getting the error that -> Unknown type name 'Node'
how can I define the function whose return type is pointer.

```
#include <iostream>
#include<stdlib.h>
using namespace std;
class tree
{
    struct Node
    {
        int data;
        Node *left;
        Node *right;
    };
    public:
    Node * toDelete(Node *root, int key);
    void insert(Node *root,int key);
    Node * createNode(int key);
    int isBST(Node* root);
    void preorder(Node *root);
    void postorder(Node *root);
    void inorder(Node *root);
    Node * search(Node *root,int key);
    Node * searchIter(Node *root,int key);
    Node * findmin(Node *root);
};
void tree :: preorder(Node *root)
{
    if(root != NULL)
    {
        cout<<root->data<<"\t";
        preorder(root->left);
        preorder(root->right);
    }
}
void tree :: postorder(Node *root)
{
    if(root!=NULL)
    {
        postorder(root->left);
        postorder(root->right);
        cout<<root->data<<"t";
    }
}

void tree :: inorder(Node *root)
{
    if(root!=NULL)
    {
    inorder(root->left);
    cout<<root->data<<"\t";
    inorder(root->right);
    }
}
void tree :: insert(Node *root,int key)
{
    struct Node *prev = NULL;
    while(root!=NULL)
    {
        prev = root;
        if(key<root->data)
        {
            root = root->left;
        }
        else
        {
            root = root->right;
        }
        
    }
    struct Node *ptr = createNode(key);
    if(key<prev->data)
    {
        prev->left = ptr;
    }
    else
    {
        prev->right = ptr;
    }
}
    Node * tree :: createNode(int key) //Unknown type name 'Node'
{
    Node * n = new Node;
    n->data = key;
    n->left = NULL;
    n->right = NULL;
    return n;  //Cannot initialize return object of type 'int *' with                              an lvalue of type 'tree::Node *'
}
int main()
{
    
}
```

Comment: Is the declaration of the struct above function declaration/definition?

Comment: no it's just the part where I want the createNode function to return the node that it has created .

Comment: [Were the answers helpful?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 1):

Keep `Node` outside `tree` class.

```
struct Node
{
    int data;
    Node* left;
    Node* right;
};
class tree
{
    ....
```

`Node` is private to your `tree` class. Hence, it is not directly accessible outside the class the way you are trying in your code.